# How do I change FormData before it submits?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, forms, form-data

I'm working on a project where I need to change FormData before it submits. I can't change the element value, I have to change the actual FormData that goes into a the POST.

I've tried changing form.onsubmit to update the value (works for some fields but others dont work due to validation checks)

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Posturl.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="">
   <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" value="">
</form>
```

I know I can create a new FormData object and can set the values of the object with formData.set('field1', 'newValue') but Im unsure on how to POST this new FormData object and not the old object.

Comment: You don't need `formData`, you can get the value of an element by `document.get...` and then do changes in js, store it as `json` and `post`.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `formdata` event listener.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('formdata', (e) => {

  const formData = e.originalEvent.formData; 
  
  formData.append('alphabet', "abcde");
  formData.append('a1b2', "123123");
});
```

source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/formdata_event

I use `e.originalEvent.formData` instead of `e.formData` (following the doc above) because `e.formData` is `undefined` And of course, don't use `e.preventDefault` on submit because it will cancel the default form request (`Doc` type request).

Comment: `formdata` and eventlistener are two concepts and do not need to be combined. They can stay on their own. For appending to formdata, no event is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately support is good but not great as of today (safari iOS 14.8 dont support it)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data by putting a event listener on the "[type='submit']" button. In the following example I am using jquery to locate the form and ajax to send a request. Hope it Helps.

```js
$("#submit-info").click(function ()
    {
    var data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    data.append("route",1); (//adding a new value)
    data.set('field','newValue'); //use the name attribute of html tag to target the respective key-value pair

    $.ajax({
        send the data(optional)
    });
});
```

```html
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="text" name="field" id="field1" value="">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-doc">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Since this uses the Ajax, if the response contains any attachments, they wouldn't get handled by the browser. So for those cases, this might not work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var formData =new FormData();
   formData.set('field1', 'sample');
   formData.set('field2', 'try');
   formData.set('field3', 'again');
    
      //delete the key
   formData.delete('field1');

   //append new value of the key
   formData.set('field1', 'test');

   
   //check all formdata values
   for(var pair of formData.entries()) 
   {
       console.log('FormData Pair ('+ pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]+')'); 
   }
```

You can try this solution by deleting the key and setting new value

```js
   var formData =new FormData();
   formData.set('field1', 'sample');
    
   //delete the key
   formData.delete('field1');

   //append new value of the key
   formData.set('field1', 'test');


   //check the formdata key if value was updated object
   for(let val of formData.values())
   {
       console.log(val);
   }
```

Comment: Is there no way to access the form data associated to an existing form? By calling new FormData(), we're creating a new instance. Or how do I send the new instance to the url in the action attribute?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply put the data in the input along with onsubmit

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Posturl.aspx" onsubmit="formData.set('field1', 'newValue');javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="">
   <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: How do I access the formData object to actually manipulate the formData being sent? If I create a new var formData = new FormData(form); it doesnt actually change the formData being sent but creates a new instance of formData @Super Penguino

Comment: delete that key and set new

Comment: @JonathanCorrin , even I face same requirement .  Form Data should be trimmed before submit , but input values should be unaffected . If you have found the solution , please do post self answer .